# Can i make asyncio.sleep() sleep for a year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I want to get `asyncio.sleep()` to sleep for a year.

Something like this:

```py
async def run():
  # first print
  print('hi')
  # wait a year
  await asyncio.sleep(31536000)
  # second print
  print('hi after a year')
```

I obviously can't test it by waiting a year, but in theory can it be done?

Comment: I really don't see why not. Nothing in the docs says you can't.

Comment: ok, ill try it.

Comment: Just keep in mind that your program will have to be running for over a year in order for you to get the second print. That means no turning off your computer, or if on a server then no server maintenance.

Comment: while it may work but in case server terminated or some other issue of daemon restored, it will break the script...and that's really unpractical, try to use something like cronjob, which you can set to run after a specific time , like a week, month year etc

Comment: Why? I'm really asking. Is this just a curiosity on whether it's possible with `asyncio` or is there a real use case for that? If it's the latter, there are other ways to do it which are intended for it, this is not what `asyncio` was really designed for.

Comment: just wondering.

Answer (score -3):

You can also test this by writing a unit test and mocking the coroutine.

```
# file1.py
async def run(seconds):
  # first print
  print('hi')
  # wait a year
  await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
  # second print
  print('hi after a year')
```

```
# test_file1.py

import asyncio
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

import file1


class AsyncMock(mock.MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class TestAsyncioSleep:
    @patch('file1.run', new_callable=AsyncMock)
    def test_fun(self, sleep_mock):
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = event_loop.run_until_complete(so_async.run(31536000))
        sleep_mock.assert_called_with(31536000)
```

I am mocking asyncio.sleep with AsyncMock() class.

Comment: You mocked out the thing you were testing! This test proves nothing.

Comment: Also, `so_async` is undefined.

Comment: so_async should be > file1.run